# How to print the array that contains the tags and the data in this xml parser?

Tags: php, xml

```
<?php

class Simple_Parser 
{
    var $parser;
    var $error_code;
    var $error_string;
    var $current_line;
    var $current_column;
    var $data = array();
    var $datas = array();

    function parse($data)
    {
        $this->parser = xml_parser_create('UTF-8');
        xml_set_object($this->parser, $this);
        xml_parser_set_option($this->parser, XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE, 1);
      xml_set_element_handler($this->parser, 'tag_open', 'tag_close');

        xml_set_character_data_handler($this->parser, 'cdata');
        if (!xml_parse($this->parser, $data))
        {
            $this->data = array();
        $this->dat1 = array();
            $this->error_code = xml_get_error_code($this->parser);
            $this->error_string = xml_error_string($this->error_code);
            $this->current_line = xml_get_current_line_number($this->parser);
            $this->current_column = xml_get_current_column_number($this->parser);


        }
        else
        {
            $this->data = $this->data['child'];

        }
        xml_parser_free($this->parser);
    }

    function tag_open($parser, $tag, $attribs)
    {
        $this->data['child'][$tag][] = array('data' => '', 'attribs' => $attribs, 'child' => array());
        $this->datas[] =& $this->data;



        $this->data =& $this->data['child'][$tag][count($this->data['child'][$tag])-1];
    echo("");
}

    function cdata($parser, $cdata)
    {
        $this->data['data'] .= $cdata;


    echo "$cdata";
    }

    function tag_close($parser, $tag)
    {
        $this->data =& $this->datas[count($this->datas)-1];
    //echo "$this->datas[]";
        array_pop($this->datas);
    }

foreach ($this->data as $i1 => $n1)     
        foreach ($n1 as $i2 => $n2)            
            foreach ($n2 as $i3 => $n3)
                printf('$data[%d][%d][%d] = %d;<br>', $i1,$i2,$i3,$n3);?>
}
$file = "BLR_HOSP-1.kml";


if (!($fp = fopen($file, "r"))) {
    die("could not open XML input");
}
$data = fread($fp, filesize($file));
fclose($fp);

$xml_parser = new Simple_Parser;
$xml_parser->parse($data);



?>
```

The foreach loop didn't work . So how do give an output of the xml file I parsed and that I have stored as an array . I want to print the tags and also the data in the tag .

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, there looks to be a few syntactical errors.  Correct the following errors first, and then let us know if the problem persists:

1. The line `printf('$data[%d][%d][%d] = %d;<br>', $i1,$i2,$i3,$n3);?>` has a closing PHP tag at the end. (see the `?>`.)
2. I'm not sure that the 'foreach' loop is correct where you've placed it.  I reviewed  the braces ( `{`, `}`) a few times to make sure I'm right.  It looks like the `foreach` function is **not** contained inside a function.  It looks like it's still inside the **class** though, which is even worse..

My suggestion is to place the 'foreach' statement, after removing the ?> characters, after the '`$xml_parser->parse($data);`' command.  (Make sure to edit it so the `$this` is replaced with `$xml_parser`.)

I haven't reviewed the rest of your code for errors--I may edit/update this answer if what I've suggested doesn't currently fix your problem, or at least help you figure out what else is wrong. :)

Comment: it works . But it still doesn't give me the date in the tags .

Comment: Have you figured this out since I last left my comment? If not, please reply. :3